# How did the Cohanim walk around the Mizbeach?

Tags: kohen-priest, beis-hamikdash, korban, health-safety-shmira, maseches-zevachim

I'm finding it very difficult indeed to understand how the Cohanim walked around the Mizbeach on a ledge which was only one Amoh wide but was also six Amos above the floor...   Seems to me that they'd always be falling off...

Comment: There were two Mizbeach's (Mizbachot?). The dimensions you're speaking about sounds like the dimensions for the inner Mizbeach. The outer Mizbeach was larger.

Comment: @salmon no they sound like the outer bigger one. The ledge was only half wya up

Comment: Jeremy Rose, [welcome to Mi Yodeya](//judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887), and thanks very much for bringing your question here! I hope you'll look around, find other information of interest, perhaps starting in our [tag:beis-hamikdash] tag, and keep asking and answering.

Comment: Related redacted and improved: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/104655/why-there-was-no-railing-on-the-5m-high-mizbeach?noredirect=1#comment349139_104655

Answer (score 6):

You are probably referring to the "Sovev" - ledge half way up the Mizbeach, which was six Amos above the floor.

The Tiferes Yisroel (צורת המזבח אות יד) writes that there was probably a Ma'akoh - fence so the kohanim should not fall off.

I have not seen this brought by other meforshim, or illustrated in any diagram of the Mizbeach (other than in בית השם on מדות פרק ג משנה ג).