# Side Ramps on the Mizbeach

Tags: beis-hamikdash, architecture-design, mizbeach-altar

Someone asked me to build him a model of the mizbeach for his class. I understand the dimensions of the mizbach from the Mesaches Middos in the beginning of the [third perek](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Middot.3.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en). It does not discuss the side ramps. I would like to know the positioning and lengths of these ramps.

Comment: What do you mean by "side ramps"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why there was no railing on the 5m high Mizbeach?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/104655/why-there-was-no-railing-on-the-5m-high-mizbeach)

Comment: @IsraelReader how does this answer my question.